# Configure custom scrolling behavior for Jupyterlab using Stylus, based on cell output length and type

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, jupyter-lab, stylus

This question is a followup question to this thread : [Jupyterlab active scroll bars for long results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816081/jupyterlab-active-scroll-bars-for-long-results)

In a notebook opened with Jupyterlab, when faced with cell outputs of different types (plots / text), and different lengths, it would be interesting to have a different scrolling behavior for each cell based on conditions checking those cells.

In my case I would like to have no scrolling when the output contains plots and when the output is less then 50 lines, but then activate scrolling and a smaller cell height when these conditions are met.

As the question mentioned before proposes the use of the browser extension [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) which is based on CSS, is there a way to modify this Stylus configuration file to include this custom behavior ?

```
.jp-OutputArea-child {
    max-height: 33em;
}

.jp-OutputArea-child .jp-OutputArea-output {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

My experience in CSS being very limited, the idea would be (in pseudo-code):

```
IF OutputArea.height >= 50 AND OutputArea.hasPlot == False: 
{
  .jp-OutputArea-child {
      max-height: 33em;
  }
  .jp-OutputArea-child .jp-OutputArea-output {
      overflow: auto;
  }
}

ELIF OutputArea.hasPlot == True: 
{
  .jp-OutputArea-child {
      max-height: None; 
  }
  .jp-OutputArea-child .jp-OutputArea-output {
      overflow: disabled; 
  }
}

ELIF OutputArea.height < 50 AND OutputArea.hasPlot == False: 
{
  .jp-OutputArea-child {
      max-height: None;
  }
  .jp-OutputArea-child .jp-OutputArea-output {
      overflow: disabled;
  }
}
```

Of course I don't expect any checks to be of this type, and the checks may differ based on the plot type (matplotlib/plotly/openturns), even if for now matplotlib checks would be sufficient.

Also Stylus [seems to be expendable using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836972/add-custom-function-to-stylus-with-javascript-api), but my knowledge there has the same limitations. And as [it seems that CSS cannot handle exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098392/conditions-in-css-based-on-the-browser) this custom behavior might have to pass over a style.js file.

Is there a jupyterlab setting or extension that already implements those behaviors, could the Stylus configuration file include these conditions, or is the only way to use a custom javascript extension?